# Informatica: Process the files only if all records have value Accepted = Y else do not process the whole file

Tags: shell, unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have multiple files with same layout as source. There is a field called 
"Accepted". Which can have values Y or N. I want to process only those files that are having values = Y for all the records.

eg):-

```
File 1
ID   Accepted
1     Y
2     N

File 2
ID   Accepted
1     Y
2     Y
```

In above case, I should process only File 1. I'm using Informatica PowerCenter for processing the files. There can be n number of files which are read as "Indirect File". Indirect file is created using pre-session korn shell script.

I prefer handling it withing Informatica Mapping, but any solutions using shell script also welcomed. The files are delimited '|' and have many fields not just "ID" and "Accepted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this using awk statement when creating indirect file:

Assume all your input files starts with name "inputfile*"

flag variable will fetch 2nd field of the file with delimiter as '|'

> A filename is added to indirect file only if there is no "N" in flag variable

```
filename=inputfile*
for f in $filename
do
flag=`awk -F "|" '{print $2}' $f`
if [[ $flag =~ .*N.* ]]
then
echo 'Skipping file as one of the record has value =N as accepted'
else
echo pwd/$f >>indirectfile
fi
done
```

Comment: It seems to be working, thanks. But is there any way to handle this using Informatica?

Comment: There is. But it's a perfect scenario for NOT doing it within PowerCenter, but take advantage of shell scripting. Otherwise you'd need to the same thing the script does in PowerCenter: use a session with Indirect File, read the contents, aggregate and check if 'N' exist in file and output the file name to a text file that will next be an input for the mapping you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Using Informatica :

1. Add currently processed filename to source.
2. Expression:- set a port with value = 1 if accepted is N else 0

   value = IIF(ACCEPTED = 'N',1,0)
3. Aggregate based on currently processed filename ; take SUM(value)
4. Filter only records having SUM(value)=0
5. Normal join with original source based on currently processed filename

This should give the required result.

```
Source --> Expression --> Aggregator --> Filter --> Joiner(join with original source)
```